# Do you need to specify both ends of a relation in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to build an Asp.NET MVC 4 application in VS2010 (.Net 4.0) with Entity Framework 5 (but I understand that not all EF5-features are supported in .Net 4.0), using scaffolded repositories.

I have a relation that I feel is rather one-sided, an Event fits in a TimeSlot. For simplicity, I wanted to model this as a property:

```
public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TimeSlotId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("TimeSlotId")]
    public TimeSlot TimeSlot { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSlot
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StartHour { get; set; }
    //... more plain int properties
}
```

However, I can't seem to get this to work at all!
When I prepopulate the TimeSlots table in the database, I try to do the following:

```
var EventRep = new EventRepository();
var TimeSlotRep = new TimeSlotRepository();
var times = TimeSlotRep.All.GetEnumerator();
times.MoveNext();

var a = new Event { TimeSlot = times.Current };
EventRep.InsertOrUpdate(a);

EventRep.Save();
TimeSlotRep.Save();
```

i.e. Get a TimeSlot from the Database, assign it to an Event, and then save everything.
However, when I try to save the `TimeSlotRepository`, I get the exception:

```
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.
```

Does anyone have an explanation as to why this attempts to edit the TimeSlot.Id property?
Does this problem relate to the fact that `TimeSlot`doesn't have a list of `Event`s?
Do you need both ends of a relation in EF to have a property/list of the opposite end?

Comment: I'd say create a separate model view of the same design in the designer and see how EF creates it.

Comment: imho, that is because `times.Current` does not belong to the same context as `EventRep`.

Comment: Why would the `TimeSlotRep` need saving anyway?  You only need a save to `EventRep`.  I don't think it's that you've not got the other end of the relationship, I'm sure I've done this recently.  Correct me if I'm wrong but that enumerator isn't disposed before the `TimeSlotRep.Save`.  What type does `TimeSlotRep.All` return?

Comment: I'm trying to save the `TimeSlotRep` because when I didn't, everything would work during the session when the `Event` is created, but when I got it out of the database during the next session, it would have `TimeSlot = null`. But you're right! Saving the `TimeSlotRep` doesn't really seem to make a difference